# Using preferred name when starting a new job

Tags: united-kingdom

I've started a new graduate job recently. My full legal first name are two names which are separated e.g. Anna Lisa.
Throughout school and university I've always been known as my first name but I thought when asked for a preferred name to be used in the company's database I'd go with my first name and half of my second name- So with the example names it would be Annali. I've decided to make this new name as I was tired of people assuming my gender during the times of when I was using only the first part of my name. However I've found out that this name will reflect on payslips and other pension benefits as the company system is all integrated. I had not known this before and I had mentioned that if my legal name is required then to use that on the database to HR beforehand. Can someone advise me if I'll face problems legally if I continue to use this name? I've also realised how complicated I've made things with this new name as none of my friends/ previous Co workers have used this and it'll be weird to change it on LinkedIn due to connections I've already made. Should I just change it back to what I've always been known as? If so how do I deal with the confusion in the team I've already joined?

Comment: Go to HR etc at your company. Anyone on here can only (badly) guess.

Comment: " I've decided to make this new name"  That's not  how the real world works.  If you want to change your name, follow the legal procedures in your area and you will avoid the issues that you have encountered in your new job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Use your legal name wherever your legal name is required.
2. Use your preferred name wherever your legal name is not required.
3. Tell people what you prefer to be called.
4. I personally wouldn't be confused and wouldn't care if I saw you using your preferred name rather than some other name that you previously went by. Probably not many people other than you would give it a second thought.

> "Oh, I see that Andrew is now calling himself Andy. Nice."

Comment: +1 I view it as no different from people who go by their middle name instead of their first.

Comment: Or People like me who prefer a contraction of their first name (Only my Mum when she's angry or a Judge calls me by my full name :D )